# weak link cocoapod dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a iOS library (say LibA) which is dependent on another iOS lib(say LibB).

The podspec of LibA has LibB as its dependency.

```
// LibA.podspec
s.dependency 'LibB', '~>1.0.0'
```

Now, I also want to use some of LibA's classes back in LibB. Cocoapods doesn't allow me to specify two hard dependencies. Is there a way I can weak link LibA to LibB ? cocoapods only allows weak linking against frameworks(UIKit, Foundation etc).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like if they both depend on each other they should be part of the same library.

Comment: Well, they cannot be as they both serve different needs.

Comment: try: s.weak_frameworks = 'LibB', '~>1.0.0'